# How to execute feature importance in Random Forest in scikit, after I fitted the model on re-sampled data with SMOTE?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, resampling

I am trying to predict an incidence of diabetes in scikit in python. My data was extremely imbalanced so I resampled the data using SMOTE on 100%, balancing the samples. I am using random forest for classification and I wanted to import feature importance after I built the model. However, the resampled datasets are now in `numpy.ndarray` and I am not able to see the feature importance results. Please help!

diabetic (1)=704 and non-diabetic (0)=4777 on the full dataset, I resampled the dataset using SMOTE on 100% balancing the minority class to majority class of the training sample
I found the best parameters by grid-search and 5fold cross-validation 
when I tried to see the feature importance I got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

So I understand that as soon as I resampled the data it coerced into ndarray but I don't know what to do next.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

sm = SMOTE(random_state=2)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train.ravel())

cl = RandomForestClassifier() 
params = {  
'n_estimators': [100, 300, 500, 800, 1000],
'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
'bootstrap': [True, False],
'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
'max_depth' : [4,5,6,7,8],
```

}

```
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=cl, param_grid=params, cv=5, verbose=0)
bestmodel= clf.fit(X_res, y_res)
cl = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=False, criterion='gini', 
max_depth=8, max_features='sqrt', n_estimators= 300) 
forestSMOTE= cl.fit(X_res, y_res)

feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(forestSMOTE.feature_importances_,
                               index = X_res.columns, columns=
                               ['importance']).sort_values('importance', 
                                                           ascending=False)
```

If someone has suggestions about what to do in order to be able to plot important features when I am using resampled sets, let me know PLEASE.

Comment: X_res is the output of `sm.fit_sample`, and hence a numpy array now and not a dataframe anymore. So no `columns` attribute in it

Comment: Yes, thank you that's what I thought, but that means there is no way to plot feature importance for a random forest? Or plot a tree for a decision tree? I am quite new to this, so there might be a solution I don't know about. @VivekKumar

Comment: You can just use X_train.columns if thats a dataframe.

Comment: I had to resample the samples as with the original set (after I split it into train and test sets), I was achieving 0% on true positive rate and about 99% on the true negative (majority class). So the best performing model was the one fitted onto X_res and I didn't think I could use features of a model fitted into X_train. But if that's the only option I guess I 'll try! If you have any ideas about why the original model could have such a bad performance please let me know!  @VivekKumar